# OMNeT++: Different results in 'fast' or 'express' mode

Tags: omnet++, inet

Used Versions: **OMNeT++ 5.0** with **iNET 3.4.0**

I created some code, which gives me reliable results in ‘step-by-step’- or ‘animated’ simulation mode. The moment I change to ‘fast’ or ‘express’ mode, it gets buggy. The following simplified example will explain my problems:

---

```
    void MyMacSlave::handleSelfMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == CheckAck) {
         std::cout << “CheckAck: “ << msg << std::endl;
    }

    if (msg == transmissionAnnouncement) {
         std::cout << “transmissionAnncouncement: “ << msg << std::endl;
    }

    if (msg == transmissionEvent) {
         std::cout << “transmissionEvent: “ << msg << std::endl;
    }

    delete msg;
}
```

There is a function, which is called for handling self-messages. Depending on what self-message I got, I need to run different if queries.

I get this correct output in step-by-step or animated mode:

```
CheckAck: (omnetpp::cMessage)CheckAck
transmissionAnncouncement: (omnetpp::cMessage)transmissionAnncouncement
transmissionEvent: (omnetpp::cMessage)transmissionEvent
```

And this is the strange output I get using fast or express mode:

```
CheckAck: (omnetpp::cMessage)CheckAck
transmissionAnncouncement: (omnetpp::cMessage)transmissionAnncouncement
transmissionAnncouncement: (omnetpp::cMessage)transmissionEvent
transmissionEvent: (omnetpp::cMessage)transmissionEvent
```

The third output line shows that the self-message is ‘**transmissionEvent**’, but the *‘if (msg == transmissionAnnouncement)’* is mistakenly considered as true as well.

---

**As shown above I get different simulation results, depending on the simulation mode I am using. What is the reason for the different output? Why is there even a difference?**

Comment: You are comparing pointers, that is, you are checking whether the message you receive uses memory that was allocated at the same place that a known message was allocated. This is not inherently wrong, but fraught with danger. Maybe you already de-allocated the memory that, e.g., "transmissionEvent" was allocated in. A memory checker (e.g., Valgrind) might help shed some light on that. A much safer alternative would be to check for message kinds or classes.

Comment: You're right. I figured out that the problem had to do with deleting my pointers and defining new ones. Your suggestion regarding the usage of message kinds was very useful and my code is working now, in every mode.

But i haven't figured out yet, why initially there was a difference between the modes.

Comment: I assume that your code worked under some conditions because your program is free to re-use memory that has been de-allocated. That is, the sequence `int* a = new int; delete a; /* ... */ int* b = new int; assert(a == b);` can yield the two pointers `a` and `b` pointing to the same memory location. Of course, this might change when different code is executing in-between the two halves of code (for example, OMNeT++ executing in fast or in express mode).

Comment: Yep. As Christoph suggests, whenever you see different behavior between different modes (like run/express etc) or between different runtime environments (like cmdenv, tkenv qtenv) you should always suspect that it has something to do with memory layout differences. Typical problems are reusing a free'd memory block. these can be spotted with valgrind. Other issues may be more hidden like iterating over an unsorted collection like a Set. The order of items in the unordered set are random and mostly depends on the memory layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Christoph and Rudi mentioned there was something wrong with the memory allocation. When a pointer is de-allocated and a new one is allocated on the same memory, there will be something wrong. The difference regarding the usage of different running modes is just a sign that there are errors to that effect.

In my case it was useful to check for message-kinds like:

```
if (msg->getKind() == checkAckAckType) {
```

instead of the method used in the originally question. I defined the message-kinds using simple enums.